# How do I create a sphere by script?

Tags: unity, c#

I want to add a sphere at runtime via script.

I have the following code which compiles fine. At runtime however, no sphere is added to the scene.

I have attached the debugger to the script, and I have set breakpoints at each line.

After the line

```
Material nMat = new Material(Shader.Find("Lit"));//I'm using the URP
```

the debugger "blanks" out, it doesn't hit the next line.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SphereMaker : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject _Sphere;

    void Start()
    {
        _Sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        _Sphere.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();

        MeshRenderer nRenderer = _Sphere.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        Material nMat = new Material(Shader.Find("Lit"));//I'm using the URP

        if (nMat == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("no mat!!\n");
        }
        nMat.color = Color.red;
        nRenderer.material = nMat;

        _Sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f);
        _Sphere.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: From your past two questions, it looks like you need to pay closer attention to the error logs in your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shader was not found.

The right name for it would be:

```
Material nMat = new Material(Shader.Find("Universal Render Pipeline/Lit"));//I'm using the URP
```